# Как правильно совокупить ресторан со звёздами Мишлена?

Tags: выбор-слов

> У ресторана «Aroma» звезда Мишлена, редкое для Рима обслуживание —
>   вышколенный стафф и внушительный винный лист.

Ещё не побывавшему (в), но заманиваемому в Рим понятно ли будет?

Нужны ли пояснения, нужно ли тире, достаточно ли "звезда" или "одна звезда"?

Comment: В данной звезде не все разбираются (кто-то задумается: хорошо ли, что звезда одна?), лучше как-то пояснить. Английское словечко "стафф" к итальянской тематике не льнёт, как и "лист" (список).

Comment: Саша, дайте ответом - автору всё покажем!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*У ресторана «Aroma» звезда Мишлен (весьма значимая для гурманов награда) и редкое для Рима обслуживание — вышколенный стафф и внушительная винная карта.*

Пояснения:

1) звезду Мишлен можно как-то охарактеризовать;

2) "Стафф" можно оставить, это слово не только английское, а общеизвестное. Например: в России разработана система автоматизации подбора персонала E-Staff Рекрутер. [Компания Datex Software - О нас | e-staff.ru](http://www.e-staff.ru/object.htm?eid=about_us)

Comment: В отличие от двоеточия, тире не предполагает перечисления всех характеристик, а означает уточнение ("в частности, ....."). Я прав?

Comment: Двоеточие и тире - это два возможных варианта. При постановке двоеточия  делается предупредительная пауза и повышается значимость ряда, При постановке тире такой паузы нет, смысловым центром является "редкое для Рима обслуживание", а дальше следует попутное пояснение. Во втором случае текст более динамичный. Поэтому выбирает автор, и мне его выбор кажется правильным. Обратите также внимание, что "обслуживание" и "звезда" находятся в однородных отношениях,  скорее они передают основное содержание.

Comment: "Стафф" стало обиходным русским словом? Ужасно.

Comment: Мне тоже оно тоже не нравится, к тому же оно многозначное: (1) персонал; (2) вещь, предмет, реквизит, даже наркотик: (3) порода собак.  Мне кажется, что из-за такого многообразия значений оно стало применяться не часто, так что автору надо подумать, как оно характеризует его стиль речи. Пример: В офисах работает «стафф» ― с утра и до вечера включены десятки компьютеров, телефоны, телефаксы, телетайпы: [Александр Журбин. Как это делалось в Америке. (1999)]. Думаю, что это слово  более уместно в качестве термина в соответствующей литературе.

Answer (score 1):

Разбор по частям.

> У ресторана «Aroma» звезда Мишлена

В утвердительном предложении опущен глагол, что и как связывает ресторан и звезду? Звезда находится рядом ("у" — это "возле" в русском языке), светится, или вы хотите сказать, что ресторану был вручен знак отличия "одна звезда Мишлен" (*Michelin*, произносится Мишле́н; не склоняется?)?

> редкое для Рима обслуживание

Это продолжение перечисления свойств, раз разбито запятой? Имеем два атрибута (звезда, обслуживание) — они действительно параметры одного уровня, чтобы идти в перечислении подряд?

> вышколенный стафф и внушительный винный лист

Тире означает, что опущено слово или часть предложения. Я не вижу опущенного и не могу предположить, что именно было выкинуто. Если это раскрытие по пунктам утверждения "редкое для Рима обслуживание" — то тогда должно быть двоеточие, а не тире.

> стафф

В русском тексте про итальянскую реальность англицизм лучше заменить на давно устоявшиеся русские эквиваленты: "сотрудники", "персонал", "штат", "команда", "коллектив". Если хочется добавить итальянской специфики — *stato maggiore* (стато маггиоре), хотя итальянец скажет точнее.

> винный лист

В русском языке используется термин "винная карта" (реже — "карта вин").

Я предлагаю следующий вариант: У ресторана «Aroma» — звезда Мишлен и редкое для Рима обслуживание: вышколенный персонал и внушительная винная карта.

Comment: Лази, какой же Вы злюка! Я автору, не знающему итальянского, но много лет прожившему в англоязычной стране, посылаю все заданные мной вопросы, на которые постепенно поступают ответы. Зачем его обижать? Текст в процессе корректуры и редактуры, и этот сайт - самое место для обсуждения языковых проблем. Спасибо Вам за то, что выловили и подчеркнули как негодное, но браниться-то к чему!

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova - у каждого из нас свои недостатки. Меня, *по-чесноку, вымораживает* то, каким якобы русским языком пишут в формальном общении (про неформал ваще молчу) якобы образованные (с верхним образованием) якобы "дарагие рассияни"

Comment: Нет, русский-то родной, но автор далёк от филологии, и потому ему в подмогу - корректура и редактура. Я сейчас проверила, отчего б этому Мишлену не склоняться, и - не нашла причин. Иностранные фамилии на согласный мы склоняем: нет Флобера, Бальзака...

Comment: (1) Правильно: "звезда Мишлен" или "мишленовская звезда". (2) Предложенное исправление улучшает ситуацию, но остается логическая неувязочка: если все стоящее после двоеточия относится только к обслуживанию, то карта вин тут лишняя, а если к звезде и облуживанию вместе, то слисок неполный, постановка двоеточия не оправдана.

Comment: @M_Г - можно я за намек а нелогичность немного обижусь? Цуть-цуть... Имем две *независимые, но стоящие упоминания* положительные позиции: звезда и обслуживание, и именно обслуживание раскрываем: есть что выпить ("а у соседей не так и они не шевелятся") и шныри, нашустрить выпивку. Большая карта - это (технически) можно считать в "обслуживание"

Comment: Ребяты, обои: про Мишлена вы оба правы; мой вопрос см. http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2526491-rejting-mishlen-zvezda-mishlen-u-restorana-pochemu-mishlen-ne-sklonjaetsja.html

Comment: @LazyBadger - Не стоит обижаться, наша цель - найти истину, эмоции тут не при чем. Не уверен, что карту вин можно отнести к облуживанию. Но допустим. Рассуждаем дальше. Чем карта вин отличается от меню? --> Значит и меню относим к обслуживанию. --> Почему меню не упомянуто после двоеточия? Возможно, оно не "редкое для Рима", а обычное. Странно для обладателя звезды. Вывод: предложение можно принять, но звезду оно не получит :).